# Xamarin and Nuance SDK

Tags: android, xamarin, nuance

I am developing an Android app in Xamarin. One of the requirement is to process voice commands. I want to use the Nuance SDK for speech processing as the voice processing needs to happen locally without sending the voice commands to the cloud. Has anybody worked with Xamarin and Nuance before? If so could you point me to some helpful article on this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which specific Nuance SDK are you using? Are you referring to Dragon Medical SpeechKit (https://www.nuance.com/healthcare/developers.html)?